# Solr and Apache web server logs

Tags: apache, solr, webserver

I have been trying to index an Apache web-sever log in txt file format with Solr.

I am facing difficulties in posting the documents. I am a newbie in Solr. I need a path to follow. Some have suggested going for Python code or Java code. But I haven't got a clue on what all things are to be followed while writing the code. I am stuck with this problem...

Comment: I need someone to tell me what is the way in which i can index an apache web server log(text file) in Solr...

Answer (score 0):

Simple steps you need to take are as follows:

- Download [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) and run it.
- Edit the [schema.xml](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml) file and add the fields you want to store index for.
- By using libraries ([Solrj](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj), Python, etc.), read the log file and index data.